# How to "launder" airplanes?

Tags: modern-age, secret-society

Deep within the Underworld, the Deathlord Einherjar rules over a desert known as the Boneyard. It is said that whenever a plane crashes on Earth with no survivors, it will be soon be found half buried in the sand in the condition it was in before takeoff.

Einherjar has decided that these planes should be returned to service in the mortal world and can deliver them to you anywhere on Earth without hassle.

Given an annual budget in the single-digit billions, how can you get aircraft with extremely checkered pasts back into service? It's best if they fly routes similar to the ones they were lost on and for the carriers they originally flew for. Using magic is prohibited, as it's bad for your spiritual development to use the supernatural to do anything that can be accomplished mundanely. Commercial and law enforcement organizations in this world are highly corruptible, but it's imperative that the true origin of the aircraft stays secret.

For the familiar, assume that this takes place in the New World of Darkness.

Comment: The major problem with this idea is that all components (well, _almost_ all components) of aircraft have extremely detailed and documented histories; without such officially documented history of all their components aircraft are not allowed to fly, except possibly between airfields in lawless places. Once an aircraft is declared "lost" all its components are invalidated in the relevant databases. How the Deathlord manages to bribe the relevant officers or hack the relevant databases may make for an interesting story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Einherjar is the world's finest AoG team ;)

The idea of an airliner returning to service after a checkered past, if you will, isn't so crazy after all.  Airliners are expensive enough assets with long enough lead times to obtain (2-3 years) that you seriously don't want to write one off if you can help it, especially if it's say a widebody jet, so the major airliner manufacturers have what are called Aircraft on Ground (AoG) repair teams that will pack up their tools, fly out to a stranded airplane (whether it dragged its tailfeathers halfway down 10,000' of runway then proceeded to belly into a mudflat or spindled itself up the rear pressure bulkhead on a fencepost), and fix it up to "like new" condition.

A great example of this comes from the below quote, referring to [Air France flight 187](http://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19880724-0):

> In 1988, a 747 aborting a takeoff bellied into a mud flat adjacent to New Delhi airport. Fully 70 percent of the airplane required AOG repair or replacement, at a total cost of $75 million. Then a mechanic, Testin worked 126 days straight in a circus-size tent dubbed the New Delhi Dome. Boeing returned the resurrected jumbo as pristine as one just off the assembly line. Two decades later, it’s still flying.

More examples of AoG work (including a description of what it takes to fix a 767 that took a fencepost up the rear pressure bulkhead) can be found [here](http://www.airspacemag.com/flight-today/airliner-repair-247-9974457/#a7eqL4fiwwVLK2wu.99).

Oh, and by the way -- if you want a known example of an aircraft that gave yeoman's service after a serious mishap, [Boeing 737-3T0 serial number #23838 is your man](http://www.airfleets.net/ficheapp/plane-b737-23838.htm).  Currently in storage after a long career flying for the Why-Not carrier (aka Southwest Airlines) as [N697SW](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?omni=Home-N-Number&nNumberTxt=N697SW), this living legend was cemented into its place in aviation history as [TACA Flight 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TACA_Flight_110) pulled off a gliding landing on a levee outside NASA's Michoud facility.

As to the paperwork? As long as things are back in factory nick as per the original drawings, *that* part will be easy ;)

Comment: So, essentially you could pay the airliner X million for the wreck left behind after the aircraft crashes, then later show up with the copy from the Underworld and sell it back to them?

Comment: @JoshuaSnider -- sort-of :P usually, the AOG team's parent company is getting paid by the airline to do this, not the other way around, if you will :P

Comment: Unless you control or corrupt the aircraft manufacturers, I expect you'd have some serious problems with component serial numbers. Repairing a mostly obliterated (no survivors, remember) aircraft might work, but it showing up with all the original components? Not likely. You'd have to falsify all the previous inspection records or replace serial numbers on every major component, inserting records into the manufacturers' databases.

Comment: @Cyrus -- nobody said Einherjar couldn't replace parts, either.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose? You have an intact, working *duplicate* of a destroyed aircraft, Then you start totally stripping it while buying and replacing all parts from the manufacturer... Might as well pay them to put it together too and just order a new plane.

Comment: @Cyrus -- actually -- for a force like this, he can simply provide paperwork that attests that the parts were returned to factory condition (reconditioned/remanufactured/overhauled/....)